# How do i find the largest file, by size, then copy to another directory

Tags: file, copy, find

how do I search for files in a directory, sort by size, then copy the largest file into another directory.
I have seen bits and pieces..yet to solve it.
I have tried the below code. However, it does not work.

```
find sourceDirectory -type f -exec ls -s {} \; | sort -n -r | head -1 | cp {} targetdirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. just needed extra support of `awk` and `xargs`

I would prefer using `du` in place of `ls -s` although they both work fine in this case.

```
find <sourceDirectory> -type f -exec du {} \; | sort -nr | head -1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I file cp file <targetdirectory>
```

Comment: Not much luck with the code i'm afraid...doesn't like head/awk or sort.....it may weel be the '\' . is it placed correctly?

Comment: @user2941090 ohh `\\` is just line break and I put it to make command more visible. See my edit if you don't like line breaks. works file for me

Answer (score 0):

The curly brace notation (`{}`) is used in the arguments for the `-exec` option for `find`, it has no meaning to `cp` in this context. You need to split this up into two separate steps, 1) find the file, and 2) copy the file.

If you are using GNU find I would suggest something like this:

```
read size filepath < <(find . -type f -printf '%k %p\n' | sort -nr)
cp "$filepath" target/path/
```

Here is an alternative that avoids temporary variables:

```
cp "$(find . -type f -printf '%k %p\n' | sort -nr | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2-)" target/path/
```

You can replace `-printf '%k %p\n' by`-exec ls -s {} \;` but printf is much more efficient.

Note that special precautions may be needed if the file names contain other than ASCII characters.

Comment: would the braces () be enough to let unix realise where to copy from?

Comment: @user2941090: It would be enough to find the largest file yes, but you cannot run the copy command from `-exec`. See my edit for an alternative that avoids temporary variables.

Comment: Not much luck with the code i'm afraid...it doesn't like '<<'

Comment: @user2941090: the less-than characters should be separated by space. Did you test the alternative option?